# What does the -g flag mean in npm install -g

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I'm interested to understand what the -g flag means.

When I type `npm install -g bower grunt-cli` in terminal, I get an error saying:

```
'bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo'
```

I get the same error if I type `sudo npm install -g bower grunt-cli`. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything without sudo, and I still get the same error. Does -g mean sudo? If so, I don't see why!

I've tried looking for -g flags/tags/options etc in google but I still wasn't sure what this flag does!

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: The -g or --global argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, actually `-g` means global install (e.g. in /usr/bin or so). And as u see, that stuff doesn't happy to be running with sudo (or root) - so just install it from user.

Btw: you can set `global` location for your current user, in this case `-g` will install packages in specified location (and not actually globally). Create `~/.npmrc` and set `prefix` to whatever location you want.
Check this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

Answer (score 3):

the `-g` flag means install the package globally on your system.
so not only in the project you are working on.

Comment: now i would like to know what the reason for the downvote is.